# Returning a vector containing objects by reference

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying to write a function that returns a vector consisting of n random Fractions. I am getting a strange error telling me to "see reference to function template instantiation, and that "class Fraction: no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'". Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have written:

```
vector<Fraction> & genV(int n) {
    vector<Fraction> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int n, d;
        n = rand() % (100);
        d = rand() % (100);
        // create a new random fraction
        Fraction *tempFraction = new Fraction(n, d);
        // push new fraction to vector
        temp.push_back(*tempFraction);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class Fraction {
private:
    int *numerator;
    int *denominator;
public:
    int getNumerator();
    int getDenominator();
    void reduce();
    int gcd(int, int);
    // constructors
    Fraction();  // default c'tor
    Fraction(int n); // create a fraction of n/1
    Fraction(int n, int m); //  Fraction n/m
    Fraction(Fraction & other);  // copy c'tor

    ~Fraction();  // destructor
    Fraction & operator=(Fraction & rhs);
    // overload assignment operator
    Fraction & operator+(Fraction &rhs);
    Fraction & operator-(Fraction &rhs);  // overload binary operator -
    Fraction & operator-();  // overload unary operator -   (negative)
    Fraction & operator *(Fraction &rhs);
    Fraction & operator/(Fraction & rhs);

    Fraction & operator++();// overload prefix ++
    Fraction & operator++(int);  // overload postfix ++
    Fraction & operator--();// overload prefix --
    Fraction & operator--(int);  // overload postfix --

                                 //  overload relational operators
    bool operator >(Fraction & rhs); // return true if *this > rhs , false elsewise
    bool operator == (Fraction & rhs);
    bool operator < (Fraction & rhs);
    bool operator !=(Fraction &rhs);

    Fraction & operator+=(Fraction & rhs);
    Fraction & operator-=(Fraction & rhs);
    Fraction & operator*=(Fraction & rhs);
    Fraction & operator/=(Fraction & rhs);

    string toString();
    char * toCstring();
    bool isZero();  // return true if *this is zero

    int power(int base, int exp);
    Fraction & operator^(int n);

    friend istream & operator >> (istream & in, Fraction & rhs);
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, Fraction & rhs);

};
#endif
```

Comment: In the `genV` function the variable `temp` is a local variable. It will go out of scope once the function returns, and the object will be destructed. What do you think happens if you return a reference to a destructed and non-existing object? Please learn about [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and return the vector *by value* instead.

Comment: You are also leaking memory in how you are using `new`.

Comment: `// copy c'tor` except it isn't.

Comment: Find out about the `const` keyword. It should be used all over your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the help. One thing: I'm required to return by reference. Is it possible to dynamically create the vector so that I can then return a reference to that vector once it accumulates Fraction objects?

Comment: See the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three.

Comment: If that is so, then I would argue that either the requirements are wrong or miss-interpreted, or that your design around the requirements is wrong. You can return a reference to a `static` or global (or namespace) variable, but then the program will no longer be thread-safe if that's a concern. And it's generally considered bad design.

Answer (score 0):

this `Fraction(Fraction & other);  // copy c'tor` isn't a copy constructor.

this `Fraction(const Fraction & other);  // copy c'tor` is a copy constructor.

And the reason why you aren't getting the default one is because you disabled the automatic generation of it with the  other declarations.